# Keeping validation on classes in .dbml file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, html

I've been trying to validate user inputs by adding HTML-attributes to properties on classes in .dbml file. (in the designer section). which it works. but when I change the design of database and try to refresh the .dbml file, those lines (HTML-attributes) gets removed from my classes even though the classes I assigned the attributes to , are not changed. I tried to add the attributes in different file since the main classes are partial, that's not possible. it doesn't let me change properties. so what should I do?

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_at_name", DbType="NVarChar(50) NOT NULL", CanBeNull=false)]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "account name is necessary")]
public string at_name
{
get
{
   return this._at_name;
}
set
{
   if ((this._at_name != value))
   {
       this.Onat_nameChanging(value);
       this.SendPropertyChanging();
       this._at_name = value;
       this.SendPropertyChanged("at_name");
       this.Onat_nameChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Data Annotations you can put validation in a seperate class and then reference that class from your partial class definition with an attribute. For example:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(PersonValidator))]
public class Person
{        
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }        
}

public class PersonValidator
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Range(0, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Invalid age")]
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

You can put the `MetadataType` on your partial class (not the one generated by VS).

Comment: one question though : in your answer the get/set functions between the PersonValidator and Person are the same. there is no difference I wonder if I change the contents of get/set function, would compiler override the previous ones or not?

Comment: The get/set in your Person class is what will be used. The PersonValidator implementations are not used, just their definitions. Thanks for marking as answer; upvote always appreciated too :)

Comment: thanks again for the answer. unfortunately I can't up-vote your answer. my reputation is not enough yet. sorry.